# Ping does not work

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, environment-variables

I am getting the error 
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
when I try to run ping www.google.com. I think this has to do with the path environment variable. I changed it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112 to make Java run on the command line, but now simple commands are not working. What should I change the path variable back to in order for this to work? (assuming that is the problem). I have Windows 10 installed.
Thank you

Comment: You changed the entire path to that Java line? What you need to do instead is append that to the existing PATH separated by a semicolon. The link that @Appleoddity shared should give you a starting point for restoring the original path.